# What If I do not mention @2x against image name in iPhone sdk

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I am working on iPhone app in which I have more than 200 images those are all 2x, but "@2x" is not mentioned again all image names and what I am doing that I am creating `UIImageVIew` half by its actual size, if Images are 100*100 then create `UIImageVIew` 50*50. In result It show me correct size and no issue in showing but I am observing is that these images are getting pixelated, these are not rich as these should be. So is this real issue If not mention @2x against image name and either it is mandatory or optional adjust auto with device to device. Kindly guide me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always put `@2x` after an image for retina devices.

When you use 50x50 `UIImageView`s for 100x100 images, it should work fine and you can hardly notice the differences. However, if it was 500x500, that would be a different story.

The real problem here is if you do like that, the image will be resized at run time whenever you used it.
With up-to-date devices like iphone 5, 5s, ipad air ... resizing, says, 200 images will not be problem. However, with old devices like iphone 4, that would be a pain in the ...

If your app becomes huge, it (may) causes some lag, and nobody wants it.

I'm not sure what's the best practice for this but I usually make 2 versions of an image, one for retina and one for non-retina

Comment: Thanks, thats much better answer, actually its not 50*50 I just throw this as an example but I am also making an iPad version where image sizes are around 1700*550. So I think I put some more extra time and make images two version. Thanks again

Comment: Just make an `@2x` version, then use `DevBox` to resize them to non-retina. It will save hours of resizing and renaming images. If you like my answer, you can upvote or accept it :)